# OPTION in apache log with localhost

Tags: apache, http, localhost

I have this thing my log, can somebody help me to trace what does this show ?

```
::1 - - [02/Oct/2014:00:00:04 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options is the request method. This is send before an ajax-request by browsers. Look into CORS.

Comment: so that doesn't indicate any security risk ?

Comment: If your app is handling ajax calls OPTIONS are send from browsers, so OPTIONS requests are normal. You should investigate the request after the OPTIONS request in your log.